# How to fix this Crash caused by my AsyncTask

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

Followed by this tutorial "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Lr37suTPpg&list=PLsoBxH455yoZZeeza9TiG8I9dGP0zz5o9" I was trying to Parse my own JSON File which  has a JSONArray with multiple JSONObjects in it but somehow the AsyncTask is having a problem which I can not resolve properly.

a View of my JSON File:

```
[
{
"type": "fuel",
"name": "Aral",
"address": "Siegmund Straße 12",
"lat": 49.8848387,
"lon": 8.6520691 },
{
"type": "amenity",
"name": "Hauptbahnhof",
"address": "Am Hauptbahnhof 20",
"lat": 49.8725, 
"lon": 8.628889,
"icon": "bahnhof.jpg" },
{
"type": "amenity",
"name": "School",
"address": "Berliner Allee",
"lat": 49.8670679,
"lon": 8.6346578,
"icon": "lala_land.jpg" }
]



> --------- beginning of crash 06-20 09:23:57.039 3193-3213/com.example.schwarzerritter.parsingandlistviewadapter
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>                                                                                                      Process: com.example.schwarzerritter.parsingandlistviewadapter, PID:
> 3193
>                                                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
> doInBackground()
>                                                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
>                                                                                                          at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>                                                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>                                                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                                                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>                                                                                                          at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                                                                                                          at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                                                                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>                                                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing
> INTERNET permission?)
>                                                                                                          at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:451)
>                                                                                                          at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
>                                                                                                          at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
>                                                                                                          at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
>                                                                                                          at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
>                                                                                                          at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
>                                                                                                          at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:365)
>                                                                                                          at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
>                                                                                                          at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492)
>                                                                                                          at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:470)
>                                                                                                          at
> com.example.schwarzerritter.parsingandlistviewadapter.MainActivity$LocationsAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:48)
>                                                                                                          at
> com.example.schwarzerritter.parsingandlistviewadapter.MainActivity$LocationsAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:41)
>                                                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
>                                                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
>                                                                                                          at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
>                                                                                                          at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
>                                                                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
>                                                                                                       Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed:
> EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
>                                                                                                          at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
>                                                                                                          at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
>                                                                                                          at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:438)
>                                                                                                          at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252) 
>                                                                                                          at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215) 
>                                                                                                          at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:142) 
>                                                                                                          at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169) 
>                                                                                                          at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124) 
>                                                                                                          at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:365) 
>                                                                                                          at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560) 
>                                                                                                          at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492) 
>                                                                                                          at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:470) 
>                                                                                                          at
> com.example.schwarzerritter.parsingandlistviewadapter.MainActivity$LocationsAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:48) 
>                                                                                                          at
> com.example.schwarzerritter.parsingandlistviewadapter.MainActivity$LocationsAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:41) 
>                                                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292) 
>                                                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
>                                                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
>                                                                                                          at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
>                                                                                                          at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
>                                                                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
>                                                                                                       Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: android_getaddrinfo failed:
> EACCES (Permission denied)
>                                                                                                          at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                          at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55) 
>                                                                                                          at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:438) 
>                                                                                                          at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252) 
>                                                                                                          at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215) 
>                                                                                                          at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:142) 
>                                                                                                          at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169) 
>                                                                                                          at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124) 
>                                                                                                          at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:365) 
>                                                                                                          at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560) 
>                                                                                                          at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492) 
>                                                                                                          at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:470) 
>                                                                                                          at
> com.example.schwarzerritter.parsingandlistviewadapter.MainActivity$LocationsAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:48) 
>                                                                                                          at
> com.example.schwarzerritter.parsingandlistviewadapter.MainActivity$LocationsAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:41) 
>                                                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292) 
>                                                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
>                                                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
>                                                                                                          at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
>                                                                                                          at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
>                                                                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

in on of the first lines it says that I maybe didn't give Internet permission which I definitely did.

Here is the AsyncClass:

```
public class LocationsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params){
            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(params[0]);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if(status == 200){
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("");
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
                    for(int i=0; i< jsonArray.length();++i){
                        Locations location = new Locations();
                        JSONObject jRealObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        location.setName(jRealObject.getString("type"));
                        location.setName(jRealObject.getString("name"));
                        location.setName(jRealObject.getString("address"));
                        location.setName(jRealObject.getString("lat"));
                        location.setName(jRealObject.getString("lon"));
                        location.setImage(jRealObject.getString("icon"));

                        locationList.add(location);
                    }
                    return true;
                }

            }catch (ClientProtocolException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(result == false){
                //msg
            }else{
                LocationsAdapter adapter = new LocationsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, locationList);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }

    }
```

For everyone in the comments complaining about the obvious message that I did not give any internet permission my android manifest xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.schwarzerritter.parsingandlistviewadapter">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: by the way, your error log is TERRIBLY formatted.

Comment: have you read the exception stacktrace at all? `Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing
> INTERNET permission?)`

Comment: Are you guys able to read my question where I mentioned that I did give internet permission?

Comment: there is even a part where I mention the excpetion 

"in on of the first lines it says that I maybe didn't give Internet permission which I definitely did."

thanks for wasting my time Vlad Matvienko.

Comment: So I take it from your edit that the problem may have been the period at the end of `android.permission.INTERNET.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is straight forward, `missing INTERNET permission?`, that means you need to give your application internet permission. Add the following to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I did give it internet permission as I already said in the question